# netbeans cannot find include file <iostream.h>

Tags: c++, gcc, netbeans, header-files

Im using net-beans 7.2 if i run helloworld.cpp its showing error that cannot find include file  (IDE cannot able to recognize any .h files ). i installed gcc, im useing Fedora 16, im trying to use CUDA plugin.

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cutil.h>
# include <iostream.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    prithf("Hii");
    return 0;
}
```

Hope someone help me.

Comment: What *exactly* is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Incidentally, `prithf` should be `printf` -- except that `<iostream>` doesn't define `printf` (it's in `<stdio.h>` or `<cstdio>`). For C++, you'd want to write something like `std::cout << "Hi\n";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, you usually dont use the .h extension for header files. For C++ header files, directly use the filename which in this case would be

```
#include<iostream>
```

Using iostream.h is deprecated.

Also write

```
using namespace std;
```

preferably after decalring all header files to import all symbols in the standard namespace into your code. That way, you wont have to write std:: everytime you want to use one.  If you're not getting what im talking about, please refer this link - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/. Understanding this is important.

For your usual C header files, usually you have to prefix a 'c' before the filename and remove the .h extension. For example,

```
#include<math.h>
```

becomes

```
#include<cmath>
```

Comment: It's not deprecated, it never was part of the standard.

Comment: @PaulManta Yeah, not part of the "official" standard. It was supported from Stroustrup's version and compilers do say "its deprecated". Thats why i wrote that !!

Comment: @PaulManta: You know, C++ actually existed for almost 20 years before "the standard" you refer to.  During that time, the de-facto c++ standard did in fact include `<iostream.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just:

```
#include <iostream>
```

?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such header file in C++. `#include <iostream>` is what you want. Certain compilers do use `<iostream.h>` for legacy code (no idea if gcc is one of them) but you shouldn't be using it.